# Django installation on a Mac running Leopard

Tags: python, django, installation

Here's my problem. I have a mac with 2.5 installed & was using django 1.1 with it. I had no problems until I decided to upgrade python & django. I uninstalled django from my mac as per the djangoproject.com website recommends. I left python 2.5 on my mac as not to interfere with pre-installed mac programs. I put python 2.6 & 3.1 on my mac via mac ports. Python boots up fine in my mac & I can switch between versions very easily via terminal. I put django on my mac. This is where it's installed:

**/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py.**

Python 2.6 is also set as python_select python26, python_select -s via macports terminal commands, Which makes it the system start up for python. I have absolutely no problem with python, it runs perfectly. When I go into the python2.6 interpreter & issue import django- print django.VERSION, I get 1, 2, 1, 'final',  0). So there should be a sym-link created for the latter. When I go to create a django-project from my system project folder via terminal, I keep getting this:

**demetrius-fords-macbook-pro-17:django_projects demet8$  django-admin.py startproject demo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 2, in 
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core.**

I have tried everything from creating my own sim-link manually to other install solutions for django and I cannot create a django project from a system command of **django-admin.py**, nor can I test the installation version via **$ django-admin.py --version**.  I can only check the django version from the interpreter as I stated earlier. Any suggestions? I am out of answers & frustrated @ this point!

Comment: Like I have written in my answer to your other question, if you want to use more then one python interpreter (2.5, 2.6, 3.1, ...), you should really use virtualenv (with pip). Virtualenv is exactly made to avoid the kind of problem you currently have. I know it's one more thing to learn but you will be rewarded really soon. Also note that on Stack Overflow it's preferable to accept an answer (if there's an acceptable answer, of course!) when you post a question.

Comment: Thank you Etienne. I'll take a look at it today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you have more than one version of Django installed; note the path (`/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py`) in the error message.  You may also not have your PATH environment variable set up correctly so that the MacPorts paths appear before `/usr/local/bin` (where you may have a link to a python.org python) and `/usr/bin` (where the Apple-supplied python is).  Your PATH should like something like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin # and so forth
```

If not, you should modify the appropriate shell startup script, probably `.bash_profile`, to modify PATH permanently.

You can test whether it works by explicitly invoking the script with the MacPorts python:

```
$ /opt/local/bin/python2.6 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py
```

Comment: I have suggest using *virtualenv* in *demet8* other question exactly for that, avoiding this kind of problem, messing with the `PATH`. With *virtualenv* you can have as many Django installations as you like without any problems (and is't true for any python package or module). It's very flexible. If you need to work on many python projects at the same time, it's a must.

Comment: virtualenv is great and I often recommend using it.  But, in this case, the OP is using MacPorts and to use *any* of the ports it provides you need to get the basics right like setting `PATH`.  And, again, OS X is a bit of a different animal when it comes to multiple Python instances.

Comment: Ned I finally got the path. What you suggested was right on the money. Thank you.......& thank you Etienne for your great advice also...

Comment: @ Etienne I did successfully set up python, django, etc on my mac via mac ports. It works great but I did see the benefit of using virtualenv & I have begun using it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way of setting up Django environments on OSX that include Apache, Python, etc.: [BitNami DjangoStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack)

You can even have multiple setups in parallel. It is self-contained, so when you are done, just remove the directory.